# Getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog Error

Tags: xml, jpos

```xml
<log realm="xml-server-8000.server.session/127.0.0.1:11800" at="2022-10-10T16:11:01.874641">
  <session-error>
    <iso-exception>
      org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
      org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.jpos.iso.packager.XMLPackager.unpack(XMLPackager.java:156)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:479)
    at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.unpack(BaseChannel.java:978)
    at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.receive(BaseChannel.java:748)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOServer$Session.run(ISOServer.java:344)
    at org.jpos.util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:76)
    </iso-exception>
  </session-error>
</log>
<log realm="xml-server-8000.server.session/127.0.0.1:11800" at="2022-10-10T16:11:01.875046700">
  <session-end/>
</log>
```

Getting SAXParseException as I am trying to connect it to JPOSClient with XMLPackager and Isomsg and my main aim is get isomsg response via JPOSclient  using Q2server. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please, follow [these guidelines] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

But in particular, please share the message you sent, and how you performed it, otherwise, it will be impossible to answer your question of whether it is the correct way or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are sending a full log to your channel instead of just an XML-formatted message. I suggest you take a look and follow the Gateway tutorial (http://jpos.org/tutorials) and of course, the programmer's guide (http://jpos.org/doc/proguide.pdf)